# How can I override just a getter in a subclass?

Tags: typescript

If I have a base class that has a getter and setter, and I override the getter in a subclass (but not the setter), I am getting `Cannot set property x of #<MyClass> which has only a getter`  ...  Do I really have to have such a superfluous method in my subclass like:

```
set x(val: any) {
  super.x = val;
}
```

??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something really weird, as per ES6 i experienced that lets say design issue, both get and set must be defined on child class. As a work around i ended up defining methods instead of accessors.

```
class A
{
    protected _val:number;
    getval():number
    {
        return this._val;
    }

}

class B extends A
{

    setval(value:number)
    {
        this._val = value;
    }

}
```

Theres a large thread [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/338)

Comment: oh ok, I thought this was typescript nonsense, but I see it's ES6 nonsense.

Answer (score 2):

This is how [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#inheriting_properties) works in JavaScript.

A getter and a setter are not separate functions. They are defined in a single [PropertyDescriptor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyDescriptor) and are thus linked. While each is optional, if one is defined then so is the other (as `undefined`).

When you override the `x` property, you are overriding the property descriptor. When JavaScript attempts to look up the property, it finds the PropertyDescriptor in `MyClass` and that PropertyDescriptor has no getter.

So the solution you have already used (`super.x = val`) is the appropriate way to handle overriding a setter while still using the super's getter.

Comment: upvote anyways nonsense implementation